# Spaceships connecting with spring (A deeply different version of Bell's spaceship paradox)

Tags: special-relativity, forces, spring

A very different version of Bell's spaceship paradox hit upon my mind for which I cannot find a convincing solution:

Two stationary spaceships are connected with a spring as shown in the figure below. Observer *A* is located somewhere in the midway of the spaceships at rest with respect to them. He sends two signals towards the spacecraft so that the signals set them in motion simultaneously, having a constant velocity *v* with respect to observer *A*. Observer *A* claims that the spring has no tension during the motion of spaceships in the *y*-direction. However, observer *B* moves towards *A* in the *x*-direction with a velocity *u*. He claims that the initial length of the spring is $\alpha_u x_0$, moreover, he observes that the receipt of the signals is no longer simultaneous, and hence, the farther spacecraft moves first, and after a while $\Delta t=\frac {ux_0}{c^2\alpha_u}$, the nearer one moves. ($\alpha_u=\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$)

[image: Spaceships connecting with spring]

From the standpoint of *B*, the final length of the spring $L_u$ is thus calculated to be:

$$L_u=x_0\sqrt{\alpha_u^2+\frac{u^2v^2}{c^4}}$$

The difference in spring's length is:

$$\Delta L_u=x_0\sqrt{\alpha_u^2+\frac{u^2v^2}{c^4}}-\alpha_u x_0$$

If the spring constant is $K_u$ from the standpoint of B, the above difference exerts a spring force to the spaceships calculated as follows:

$$F_u=K_u\Delta L_u=K_u x_0 (\sqrt{\alpha_u^2+\frac{u^2v^2}{c^4}}-\alpha_u)$$

One observer detects tension, whereas the other one does not. What is wrong with my calculations?!

(Recall that both observers are inertial)

Comment: Can you be more precise about why it's problematic for one observer to detect tension while the other doesn't?

Comment: @WillO Assume that the spring or thread is made of some bio-materials that can be devastated under specific pressures. $A$ asserts that they remain alive all during the travel, whereas $B$ claims otherwise. (Paradox)

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry why is it any different to length contraction of a spring made of the same bio-materials which are devastated under compression?

Comment: @MarcoOcram I do not get your point. Would you elaborate more on it?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry of course! I'm delighted you replied, by the way, as I imagined that after five years you might have lost interest! My point is that the gist of your question is to explain an increase in length, given that it would lead to a breaking of a fragile spring. Standard length contraction, by the same argument, would also lead to the breaking of a fragile spring (by compression instead of contraction), so is there really a new issue in your question, or is it the same conceptual problem as length contraction?

Comment: @MarcoOcram Thanks for the clarification. In the traditional length contraction, the spatial "dimension" is measured to be smaller from the viewpoint of the lab observer, which does not produce any tension in the contracted object. But, in this example, the nonsimultaneous motion of the spacecraft seems to produce a length expansion that differs from the traditional length contraction, which may result in a permanent tension in the string.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry thanks but 'traditional' length contraction is also the result of non simultaneity, so I'm struggling to see why you accept one phenomenon relating to non-simultaneity without explanation (ie you accept that length contraction doesn't produce tension) yet you want an explanation of the other phenomenon. I'm not saying you are wrong but I'm just trying to tease out the logic.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I think you are right meaning that it is possible for both observers not to detect any tension for the string since non-simultaneity probably does not allow any tension to appear in this example as well as in the examples that traditionally involve the Lorentz contraction.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's right, but I'll put some more thought into it and see if I can find a more convincing argument that leaves no room for doubt. All the best!

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry I think I've worked it out, but please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake in your reasoning is to imagine that the spring extends in the frame of B once it starts moving to the right with velocity v. That's not what is happening. Instead, what is happening is a reduction in the effect of length contraction. Remember that length contraction only occurs in the direction of motion of the contracted object. There is no length contraction  at right angles to the direction of motion. That means that a spring that is moving parallel to its length will be maximally length contracted according to the standard formula. A spring that is moving at right angles to its length won't be length contracted at all. In between those two extremes, the spring will be length contracted to some intermediate extent. So in the example you give, before the rockets start moving right, the spring is moving parallel to its length in the frame of B, so it is maximally length contracted. Once the rockets start moving, the spring is no longer moving parallel to its length in the frame of B- instead it is moving at an angle, and therefore the extent of its length contraction will be reduced. So the degree of length contraction differs between the two scenarios- the proper length of the spring doesn't change so there is no tension.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question needs to be put in the more general framework of Born rigidity.

I rather like the following thought experiment:
You have a very long cilinder, freely suspended in space, The cilinder is long enough that for an observer moving along the length of it simultaneity is observably shifted. For an observer at rest relative to the cilinder all the constituent parts of the cilinder are simultaneous. For an observer moving along the length of the cilinder the end points are not at the same time.

Now start a rotation of the cilinder, a rotation around the long axis. You make sure that no deformation of the cilinder is introduced. For the observer at rest relative to the cilinder's center of mass the shape of the cilinder remains the same. For the observer moving along the length of the cilinder (hence different simultaneity) one endpoint started rotating before the other endpoint. The implication is that for the moving observer starting the rotation introduces a distortion from a straight cilinder to one that is twisted.

These thought experiments (tethered spaceships scenario, your thought experiment, the spinning cilinder scenario), have the theme of Born rigidity in common.

The general lesson from Born rigidity thought experiments is that for bodies with spatial extent special relativity implies the possibility of distortions of materials that do not have a counterpart in non-relativistic physics.

When a group of mutially tethered objects goes through an acceleration phase then different observers may find themselves attributing different amounts of stress in the tether.

By itself the fact that in your thought experiment you find different observers attributing different amounts of stress in the material is not necessarily a problem; depending on the circumstances different amounts of attributed stress may actually be expected.

Clearly, issues of Born rigidity are very hard to get right. If memory serves me: for several years it was not known how to show that special relativity predicts a null result for the Trouton-Noble experiment. Max von Laue argued that for an observer moving relative to the apparatus there is particular stress in some of the material, the potential energy of that stress has a corresponding inertial mass, and that contribution to inertial mass must be taken into account in order to arrive at the prediction of the null result.

Comment: If one observer detects stress, whereas the other one does not, I am wondered why - in the main Bell's spaceships - most of the physicists try to justify the existence of tension from the standpoint of both observers!

Comment: "different observers may find themselves attributing different amounts of stress in the tether". Amount of mechanical stress (readings of a dynamometer) can hardly depend on chosen reference frame, it is absolute. It is unlikely there is any mechanical stress in this spring in any reference frame, relativistic twist of the cylinder is a very good example. Twist of the cylinder is purely relativistic and "strain" of the spring also. There is no reason for mechanical stress in this case.

Comment: @albert Erm... by it's nature, a dynamometer needs to be _physically attached_ to the object it is taking a measurement from. In any measurement setup the measuring device is co-moving with the object it is measuring. That is why I wrote: different observers will _attribute_ different stress. That said: in the Bell spaceship scenario the tether between the ships is a stress sensitive device. When stretched beyond its limit the tether will snap. Special to the Bell spaceship scenario: the tether is neither co-moving with the leading spaceship, nor with the trailing spaceship.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say a long truck drives fast along a four-lane highway, the truck is Lorentz-contracted. The road is icy, which causes the driver to lose control. The truck turns sideways and keeps on moving. Now the truck is not contracted. Not along its length.

The turning of the truck caused an increase of length of the truck. That did not cause any tension.

Now, in the picture in the first post we can see a fast moving contracted spring that gets turned by two rockets. The spring gets longer and that does not cause any tension.

Well somehow I feel that the lack of tension in the spring has now been explained - by the truck example.

Comment: Nope, you just gave another example without any attempt at the answer.

Comment: Here's a formula: F is tension force exerted on a rod, k is angle of the rod, v is velocity of the rod, L is length of the rod:  F(k,v,L)=0    Anyone disagree with the formula?:)