# Subtle problem in length contraction

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose a particle moves with respect to objects.

Does length contraction refer to the contraction of the particle, or to the separation between objects? It seems to me it can't be both. The former refers to the particle *in* space while the latter refers to space *itself*.

Perhaps we must choose one perspective but not both at the same time.

Comment: Relevant: [1] https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145458/  [2] https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/376562/  [3] https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/390914/

Comment: "Does length contraction refer to the contraction of the particle, or to the separation between objects?"  No and no.  It refers to the transformation between two frames.